# IPython notebook does not capture all console output

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

within my code I use a Python package that calls external programs which write their output to the same console that IPython is running in. If I now run the same code from an IPython notebook, the output is not written to the notebook output cells, but into the console that the IPython notebook server is running in.

Do you know if it is possible to capture this output somehow, and then display it within the IPython notebook? I'm on Xubuntu 14.04, by the way.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/redirecting-all-kinds-of-stdout-in-python/) gives you nice and comprehensive description of your problem and potential solutions. You need to try it out for yourself with your specific setup.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this interesting article out to me! I was in the meantime able to solve my problem with a built-in function from the package I use, though.